# 3G modem: simultaneous sending SMS and having active Internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, sms, gsm, 3g, modem

I am writing client-server application.
The client sends some messages to the server by using different transports: SMS and Internet (VPN, TCP server).
On the client's PC I have 1 3G modem which I use for both: sending SMS and establishing Internet connection.
I connect to Internet via ubuntu's Network Manager.
For sending SMS I use smstools3. Actually it doesn't matter what tools I used.
I found that it had been impossible to send SMS if there had been active Internet connection established via the same modem.

I tried to connect to Internet without the Network Manager. I manually setup pppd (with no lock param) using the manual from [here](http://www.techytalk.info/manage-gsm-mobile-broadband-connections-without-network-manager-ubuntu-mint-debian/). The connection worked fine, but it did not solve the problem.
Then I tried to use different modem's ttys for sending SMS and connecting to Internet (my modem has 2 ttys). It also did not help. Looks like only 1 tty of my modem can be used to do the job.

Now I have only 2 ideas:

1. Don't do the things simultaneously. Separate them in time: start smstool daemon, send SMS, stop the daemon, establish Internet connection, send msg, stop the connection.
2. Try to use GSM multiplexing like described here [gsm mux](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=211) I am not sure about the result because the mentioned project (gsm mux) looks dead.

Do you have any other ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: BTW, I use the following things:  
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  
Smsd: 3.1.14  
Modem: Huawei E800 ExpressCard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

Huawei E800 couldn't be used. Instead, I used E369. That modem has 3 ports (3 ttyUSB in /dev/). If I use the 1st tty for the Internet and the second for sending/receiving SMS, then the problem disappears.
Note that E800 also has 2 ttys, but it doesn't solve the problem.

I think I known how to figure out whether a modem can be used for simultaneous SMS and Internet. Need to send "AT+CMUX=0" to the modem. If it answers that the operation is not supported, then you have to try different modem.

Also I met 1 more problem on Ubuntu 13.04. 
If I used the ubuntu's NetworkManager to set up Internet connection, then it blocked my modem. So, the modem couldn't be used to send/recv SMS. 
I found the solution - didn't use NetworkManager. Instead, I set up Internet connection with wvdial. It solved the problem.

Comment: i have 3 ttyUSB but when i try ti use USB1/0 nothing is happend, how can i configure that the internet will go via USB1 instead USB2?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you still may get SMS using AT command output even if you get AT+MUX=0 "not implemented"
Connect to modem port:

```
socat - /dev/ttyUSB2, crnl
```

Then follow output unless you get +CMT command. Output may be either clear text or PDU. Clear text is obviously readable. PDU may look like:

```
+CMT: 0,32
07915892000000F001000B915892214365F7000021493A283D0795C3F33C88FE06CDCB6E32885EC6D341EDF27C1E3E97E72E
```

If you get PDU - you need to decode it. For example here: [PDU decoder](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/online-sms-pdu-decoder/)

Comment: It may be that [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)